# I get this syntax error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

this is the problem i have to answer:

Write a program to input exam scores (out of 100) until you enter 'quit'. After you finish entering exam scores the program will print out the average of all the exam scores.

HINTS:
To figure out the average you must keep a running total of exam scores and a count of the number entered.
Try to make the program work 1 time, then figure out the exit condition and use a while True: loop.

Example Run:
Enter exam score or type 'quit': 100
Enter exam score or type 'quit': 100
Enter exam score or type 'quit': 50
Enter exam score or type 'quit': quit
Number of scores 3. Average is 83.33

This is my code:

```
count = 0
average = sum
while True:
    num =input('Enter an exam score or type "quit":')
    count = count + 1
    average = sum(num)
    print ('the total of exams is %d and the average is %f' % count, average)
    if num == 'quit':
        break
print ('this is ok for now')
```

Comment: You need to `int(..)` the `num` first.

Comment: thanks, but this is what i got: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: But you input the elements one by one. So you should use a running variable that adds `num` each time...

Answer (score 0):

This line has a lot of problems: `average = sum(num)`.

An appropriate input for `sum` is a list of numbers to be summed. In your case, you instead have a single number or the word "quit".

What you need to do is keep track of the count and the running total, then do your division at the end:

```
total = 0
count = 0
while True:
    # With raw_input, we know we are getting a string instead of
    # having Python automatically try to interpret the value as the
    # correct type
    num = raw_input('Enter an exam score or type "quit":')
    if num == "quit":
        break
    # Convert num from a string to an integer and add it to total
    total += int(num)
    count = count + 1
average = total / count
print("The total number of exams is {} and the average is {}".format(count, average))
```

Answer (score 0):

My take would be using the `statistics` module and `sys` for exiting. Also handling of non-int (or non-float) input and printing a proper message instead of exiting with ValueError

```
import statistics, sys

notes = []
count = 0
average = 0   # or None
while True:
    note = input('Enter score: ')
    # handle quit request first, skip any calculation
    # if quit is the first request
    if note == 'quit':
        print('Program exit. Average is %s' % average)
        sys.exit()
    else:
        # test if the entered data can be an int or float
        try:
            note = int(note)     # can be replaced with float(note) if needed
            count += 1           # increase the counter
            notes.append(int(note))
            average = statistics.mean(notes)    # calculate the average (mean)
            print('Total %s average is %s' % (count, average))
        # just print an error message otherwise and continue
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a valid note or "quit"')
```